# Trouble with jQuery and .attr('value')

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list, with a value on each list item like so:

```
<ul>
    <li value='red'>red</li>
    <li value='grn'>green</li>
    <li value='prp'>purple</li>
    <li value='blu'>blue</li>
</ul>
```

I needed to retrieve the value of the list items, so turned to jQuery (1.3.2):

```
$('li:first').val();
```

This throws a javascript error.  I'm forgiving of jQuery here as li is not a form element, I'll just do it the 'hard way' i tell myself:

```
$('li:first').attr('value');
```

This does not throw an error, but it does return '-1' no matter which element I am matching.  Clearly, -1 is not the value for any of the elements.  After fiddling for a few minutes to make sure I've spelled everything correctly I try this on a whim

```
$('li:first').attr('Value'); //notice capital V
```

This returns 'red', the correct value.  To make sure I am not crazy, I try some more

```
$('li:first').attr('vAluE');
$('li:first').attr('vaLue');
$('li:first').attr('VALUE');
```

It appears as though every combination of mixed cases work, so long as you do not use only lowercase 'value'.  It works fine if I rename my attribute to anything other than 'value' (non-valid html), but I would sooner keep it valid if I could.  Is there a reason jQuery is behaving like this, or should I consider it a bug?

-edit-
I realize the value attribute has been depreciated on the li element.  The real issue I am having is that regardless of it being depreciated, I am infact using an attribute named 'value' and asking jQuery to tell me it's value.  It is incorrectly returning -1.

Comment: When you changed the case in the jquery call, I assume you also changed the case that was defined in the HTML?

Comment: No, the case was NOT changed in the HTML, it was left as all lower case.

Comment: The `value` attribute was deprecated on `<li>` elements in HTML 4.01. Also, it was meant to hold numeric values only, and only for `<li>` of ordered lists (not unordered) as you have. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may possibly be related? http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4160

In summary:

> **resolution** set to *invalid*
>   In HTML4 the value attribute of an li gives you the ordered list number:
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp
>
> So the cause lies outside jQuery, you can see it from this example:
>
> `<li id="arf" value="dog"></li>`
>   `alert(document.getElementById("arf").value);`

Comment: I'll provide the full link next time rather than just quoting the same w3schools.com page *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

Value is used in lists only with ordered lists like so:

```
<ol>
  <li value="5">Item One</li>
  <li value="10">Item Two</li>
</ol>
```

This would be displayed like this:

*5. Item One*
*10. Item Two*

This could be the reason jQuery is acting funny.

Comment: Sounds plausible - the browser is likely correcting the incorrect usage of `value` in a `UL`, which would explain the -1.

Comment: I have just tried swapping to an <ol> and it behaves in the same manner.

Comment: That's not surprising. Browsers likely expect a `LI` to have a numeric value, as there's a legitimate use for the attribute in those tags.

Comment: Right, but per w3c, "The value attribute sets the number of a list item. The following list items will increment from that number." It's not meant to be used as a selector and further it's depreciated.  You should use a class instead.

Comment: I am not using it as a selector, I'm using it to store a string.  However you hit on a clue, if I put integers in the value attribute jQuery correctly returns the integer.  I guess it's being cast to an integer somewhere in there.  I still find it very abnormal that changing the case of the attribute causes it to return the string value.

Answer (score 0):

@jeerose's explanation sounds plausible to me. Any reason you can't change `value=""` to `val=""`?

Comment: Not any particular reason, I have already done so for the short term. I'm really more frustrated that jQuery is returning -1 for an attribute that is there, it feels like its lying to me.

Comment: Well, you're providing an invalid data type for the list item's value field - it expects a number. If you give invalid data to the browser, you shouldn't be surprised it's ignored...

Answer (score 0):

`value` is depreciated for `li` and was used to set the number of the list item. Using another name works.